# 70/30 Automatic Split in Vim

Tags: vim

I've seen many VIM users have a 70/30 vsplit that automatically resizes to 70% for the active buffer. Example of this are Jose Mota's tutorials on Tuts+ but I've seen it in other screencasts as well. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that he is using some sort of `'winheight'` and '`winminheight'` trick. Example:

```
set winheight=999
set winminheight=5
```

This works because `'winheight'` is the minimum height for the active window. All other windows will use `'winminheight'` for their window height.

For more help see:

```
:h 'windheight'
:h 'winminheight'
```

Comment: I see. He does have these lines in his .vimrc:

set winheight=5
set winheight=999
set winminheight=5
set winwidth=84

However when I try that I get: `E36: Not enough room` error

Comment: From `:h 'winminheight'`: Don't use a large number, it will cause errors when opening more than a few windows.  A value of 0 to 3 is reasonable.